# Battery charged percentage not increasing on Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6

Tags: lenovo, battery-charging-threshold

I have recently shifted from Windows 10 to Ubuntu on a Lenovo legion 5 5-15ACH6 with ryzen 7 5800 H and RTX 3050 GPU.

In Windows, I used the Lenovo vantage to limit my charging up to 60%. But after I switched to Ubuntu 20.04, the laptop battery percentage is not increasing. It is showing that it's connected to AC adapter but the percentage is not increasing.

How can I make my battery percentage reach 100?

Comment: (1) you should have kept Windows as dual-boot if you used proprietary software with such low level access to hardware/firmware (UEFI). (2) There's no software for Linux that can revert the changes made by the Windows software. (3) In any case try to update UEFI (it's recommended even for brand new machines) but it probably won't change the settings controlled by the software.

Comment: How can I update the UEFI?

Comment: Go to your specific model support pages at Lenovo's and follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

or just use:
find / -type f -name conservation_mode

open the file with nano and change 1 to 0

you can also use my shell script for easy On and Off
https://github.com/MaksBal/LenovoConsMode

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Windows, switch the battery saver off within the Vantage Software, now your battery can charge to 100% again, even after wiping windows again and fully installing Ubuntu. I just re enabled the charging threshold in Linux using TLP back to 60%